# Use D3 and Shiny to implement `identify()` in R

Tags: javascript, r, d3.js, shiny

I asked [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13714724/688080) on how to plot dynamically according to user interactions, whose solution
works quite well on my machine.

Now I want to make an on-line version and host it with [Shiny](http://shiny.rstudio.org/).

I have tried to put the code into `server.R` and invoke the `iden()` function inside `reactivePlot()`, but the part of `identify()` does not take effect.

So, any hints on this task?

Comment: Did you try the [rCharts](https://github.com/ramnathv/rCharts) package to create Javascript "charts" from R ? This is easily embeddable in a Shiny App.

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent I've noticed this package but this question is asked before its invention.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I have seen yesterday an interactive ggplot on [Timely Portfolio blog](http://timelyportfolio.blogspot.fr/) but I have not been able to find it again today.

Answer (score 2):

Try this [gallery item.](http://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/movie-explorer.html)  It uses ggvis to accomplish this goal in shiny.
In case the gallery disappears, here is some minimal code that will produce a tooltip, similar to `identify()`, using ggvis.

```
require(ggvis)
mtcars$model<-rownames(mtcars)
mtcars %>% ggvis(~wt, ~mpg,key:=~model) %>% 
  layer_points() %>% 
  add_tooltip(function(df) df$model)
```

And, a more complete, but still minimal example:

```
require(shiny)
require(ggvis)
mtcars$model<-rownames(mtcars)

shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel(h2("GGVis to Identify Points")),
      mainPanel(ggvisOutput("carsplot"))
    )
  ), 
  server = function(input, output) {
    vis <- reactive({ 
      mtcars %>% ggvis(~wt, ~mpg,key:=~model) %>% 
        layer_points() %>% 
        add_tooltip(function(df) df$model)
    })
    vis %>% bind_shiny("carsplot")
  }

)
```