# Zoom in the subplot in the existing plot in R

Tags: r

I have the following plot in R. I would like to have a subplot in the existing plot form `x =[0, 2]` and `y=[0, 2]`, also I want to zoom into that subplot. How can I do this in R?

```
 lin <- data.frame(x = c(0:6), y = c(0.3, 0.1, 0.9, 3.1, 5, 4.9, 6.2))
 linm <- lm(y ~ x, data = lin, subset = 2:4)
 plot(y ~ x, data = lin)
 abline(linm)
```

Comment: [Related](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13714724/how-to-draw-a-zoom-in-effect-in-r/13728281) question, answers, comments..

Comment: @Julius. I have seen that question, but that fuction just zoom in the point not the line.

Answer (score 4):

You can do this for example:

```
lin <- data.frame(x = c(0:6), y = c(0.3, 0.1, 0.9, 3.1, 5, 4.9, 6.2))
linm <- lm(y ~ x, data = lin, subset = 2:4)
plot(y ~ x, data = lin)
abline(linm)
## to overlap the 2 plots
par(new=TRUE, oma=c(3,1,1,2))
## create a layout to plot the subplot in the right bottom corner
layout(matrix(1:4,2))
## use xlim and ylim to zoom the subplot
plot(y ~ x, data = lin,xlim=c(0,2), ylim=c(0,2))
abline(linm)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. This subplot is ok , but how can i zoom in to this subplot or make it bigger ?

Answer (score 2):

You can change the limits of a plot using the xlim and ylim arguments to the plot function. For example

```
plot(y~x, data = lin, xlim=c(0,2), ylim=c(0,2))
```