# Connecting multiple panels with lines

Tags: r, grid

I've been recently dealing with multi-panel plotting in R. I've been trying to plot for example two graphs (par(mfrow=c(1,2)) and connect a point from the first one to the point at the second one.

For example we have>

```
par(mfrow=c(2,1)
plot(15,15)
plot(15,3)
```

My question is how do I draw a line from the first point in the first graph to the second point in the second graph? I've heard of the Grid package but I can't seem to make it work.

Thanks.

Comment: Strongly related, if not a dupe: [How to draw a line across a multiple figure environment in R?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9985013/903061)

Comment: There are only horizontal lines, normalized to y-axis. I want to connect the dots according to their coordinates in different grids.

Comment: What exactly did you try with grid that didn't work?

Comment: guess we aren't interested in base answers eh @JoshO'Brien? the gold badge quick trigger crew strikes again

Comment: @rawr Base answers are just fine! It's the question that's a duplicate, in my opinion.

Comment: Mark it as duplicate or not, you kind of didn't help me but the first answer did the job very well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the example I found, it may be useful for you:

```
layout(matrix(c(1,1,2,3), 2, 2, byrow = TRUE))
plot(runif(10), type='b', ylim=c(0,1))
x.tmp <- grconvertX(4, to='ndc')
y.tmp <- grconvertY(0.9, to='ndc')
plot(runif(20), type='l', ylim=c(0,1))
par(xpd=NA)
segments( 10, 1,
grconvertX(x.tmp,  from='ndc'), grconvertY(y.tmp, from='ndc'), col='red' )
plot(runif(20), type='l')
```

Comment: thanks, this clarifies it for me.