# Draw line between multiple plots in R

Tags: r, plot

I would like to add a line that goes between two separate plots in R.

I created the multiple-plot image using par(mfrow = c(2, 1)) as follows:

```
par(mfrow=c(2, 1))

x_values <- c(1:6)
y1_values <- c(6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1)
y2_values <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)


plot(x_values, y1_values, xlim = c(1, 6), ylim = c(1, 5))
abline(v = 2)

plot(x_values, y2_values, xlim = c(1, 6), ylim = c(1, 5))
abline(v = 2)
```

I would like the vertical line at (x = 2) to connect *between* the two plots, like this:

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9985013/how-do-you-draw-a-line-across-a-multiple-figure-environment-in-r