# How to add a line across multiple plots in R

Tags: r

Does anyone know how to add a line across multiple plots in R. I can't think of a ways to do this.

I am trying to connect the larger blue dots in the second image which have values over 80 to the next chart by a line that goes across both.

[image: img]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a rough and dirty solution (for more fine-grained solutions, see [How do you draw a line across a multiple-figure environment in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9985013/how-do-you-draw-a-line-across-a-multiple-figure-environment-in-r)):

**DATA**:

```
par(mfrow = c(2,1))
plot(rnorm(100))
plot(rnorm(100,50))
```

**SOLUTION**:

Use `par(xpd = NA)`to clip plotting to the device region:

```
par(xpd = NA)
abline(v = 80)
```

**RESULT**:
[image]